# How to Setup React Breakpoints in Chrome?

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, breakpoints

When I step through or step over a function, chrome keeps switching to bundle.js, runtime.js, react-dom.development.js and other external react files instead of stepping through my source mapped file. Not sure why this is happening, but it's making it impossible to debug.

I'm using webpack with babel. My webpack config looks like this:

```
const path = require('path')
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin")
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack')

    module.exports = {
        devtool: 'inline-source-map',
        entry: ['@babel/polyfill', './src/index.js'],
        output: {
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
            filename: 'bundle.js',
            publicPath: '/'
        },
        devServer: {
            contentBase: 'dist',
            historyApiFallback: true
        },
        plugins: [
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                filename: 'index.html',
                template: './src/public/index.html'
            }),

            new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
                filename: "[name].css",
                chunkFilename: "[id].css"
            }),
            new Dotenv()
        ],
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.scss$/,
                    use: [
                        "style-loader",
                        { loader: 'css-loader', options: { sourceMap: true} },
                        { loader: 'sass-loader', options: { sourceMap: true } }
                    ],
                },

                {
                    test: /\.css$/,
                    use: [
                        "style-loader",
                        "css-loader"
                    ]
                },

                {
                    test: /\.js$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    loader: 'babel-loader'
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Robert! Did you solve this eventually? I would be very thankful for your advice as I've got the same issue)